# Как правильно создать superuser в django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

При попытке создать superuser через pycharm выдает следующие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До этого пользовался makemigrations и все было норм, ошибок в указанных строках быть не может

Comment: makemigrations использовали, а после этого команду migrate выполнили?

Comment: По-моему, нет.  До команды createsuperuser все работало хорошо, а сейчас даже makemigrations и migrate выдают такие же ошибки

Comment: Я просто не знаю что за инструмент вы используете, там точно не надо писать команду полностью? python manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: Заработало) Перезапустиk pycharm, внес небольшие изменения, дальше makemigrations-migrate-createsuperuser и все отлично, спасибо:)